# Contains method vs strict equality

Tags: javascript, html

What is the difference between
`todo.classList === 'completed`
and
`todo.classList.contains('completed')`

I'm not sure if I'm misinterpreting their usage or my code is written poorly but i'm confused as to why the latter selects the elements with the completed class but the former selects all options in my select tag.

Comment: can you add the usage for that in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference between `todo.classList === 'completed'` and `todo.classList.contains('completed')`

It makes no sense to compare `classList` to a string, because it is an array-like data structure. Go with `el.classList.contains(str)`.

If you are certain your element has only one CSS class, you could do `el.className === 'completed'`, or if it is at least garanteed to be the first class, `el.classList[0] === 'completed'`. But you shouldn't.

```js
const todo = document.querySelector('div');

console.log(todo.className === 'completed'); // true
console.log(todo.classList.contains('completed')); // true
```

```html
<div class="completed"></div>
```

Comment: A good answer, but should include an explanation to be a great answer.

Comment: `el.classList[0] === 'completed'` should be avoided as the order of classes shouldn't affect a DOM element.

Comment: Also the "standard" way to access the nth `DOMTokenList` element is through the use of `el.classList.item(nth)`; as `DOMTokenList` works similarly to an `Array` you could still use `el.classList[nth]`. Also to convert `DOMTokenList` to an `Array` simply use `[...el.classList]`.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the clarification. Edited.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that for me. I was learning how to use the contain method and I just wanted to see other ways I could get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Here are all the methods you can use with classlist. Contains will return a boolean value whether an element has the class you pass with it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: There are *much* better resources than w3s... I highly recommend MDN, which is also easy to search (google): `mdn classList`. Also ensure to include the relevant excerpt. "The [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is a read-only property that *returns a live DOMTokenList collection of the class attributes* of the element. This can then be used to manipulate the class list."

Answer (score 1):

`.classList` returns a `DOMTokenList`. `DOMTokenList` works similarly to an array, but doesn't have all the `.map()`, `.forEach()` etc. cool stuff of it.

`todo.classList === 'completed'` won't work as you want be able to compare a `DOMTokenList` to a `String`.

`todo.classList.value === 'completed'` will work only if the only class of `todo` is `completed`. This should NOT be used.

`todo.classList.contains('completed')` will work if at least one of the classes of `todo` will be `completed`. This is the best way to do it.

Here are a few tricks you might need to work with `DOMTokenList`s:

```
[...todo.classList]; //convert to array
todo.classList[0]; //unofficial way to get the nth class name
todo.classList.item(0); //standard way to get the nth class name
```

Answer (score 0):

Your usage is not correct.

contains can be used with classlist. You cannot directly put condition on classlist method.

```
   event.target.classList.add('class3');
   event.target.classList.remove('class1');  
   event.target.classList.contains('class2'); // To check  class is present or not it returns boolean value.
   event.target.classList.toggle('class4');
```